# R. I want to exclude values in an ANOVA with a loop

Tags: r, loops, anova

I would like to check for the influence of the datapoints I use for an anova by excluding them:

```
wanted =(1:10 !=10)
wanted
summary(aov(log(Sdrtl)~location,subset=wanted))
```

In stead of excluding 1:10 manually, I would like to make some kind of loop so that all anova's flow out at once. I'm a beginner and I tried following:

```
for (i in 1:10){
    wanted =(1:10 !=i)
        summary(aov(log(Sdrtl)~location,subset=wanted))
    }
```

, which does not give what I want. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that `summary` doesn't print anything - it returns an object (which you ignore).

```
# This will print the summaries
for(i in 1:10) print(summary(aov(log(Sdrtl)~location, subset=1:10!=i)))

# This will return a list of all summaries
x <- lapply(1:10, function(i) summary(aov(log(Sdrtl)~location, subset=1:10!=i)))
x # prints the summaries
```

The second version is more useful since you can store the result and analyze it...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see whether the `influence.measures` function in base R already does what you want?  It computes a range of leave-one-out diagnostics ...